# Problem with hair particle system, a problem with the mirror

Tags: particles, hair

Earlier i was working with the hair particle system, it was working fine, but later (now), after giving a break, i found that i have an issue with the mirror while adding hair to my character.

[image]

The mirror is malfunctioning, i didn't touch any config, everything is the same just like earlier. the below part of the hair is what i worked earlier and the upper part with some random hair on a side is what i recently did.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the bug is only present on the version 2.74, when I switch to the 2.77 this problem is not there anymore, still I want to hear your opinion, guys.